# Firebase InfiniteScroll didnt run as expected

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, infinite-scroll

So I am making a Social-Media App, and everything is all good now. The last problem is that every time I open the app, All the posts get fetched by the API and right now it have already been a problem. I have tried to read all the sources to know how to make one but now I'm stuck.

My App used Firebase + Redux + React so to implement this is a bit harder than other app. I have created a function to fetch the first set of the posts list and it work fine but the second function of the list return the same as the first one even thou I have insert startAfter() with limit()

**WHAT I WANT: I want the second functions to fetch the next query of posts for me without replicate any of the posts in the first function and I also want to understand what I need to pass in startAfter**

**REALITY: The second functions do run and it do get new posts but it was the same posts, so if my lists have 5 posts it return 2 sets of 3 posts that looks the same**

This is my first functions of Firebase :

```
exports.getFirstSetOfPosts = (req, res) => {
    db.collection('posts')
    .orderBy('createdTime', 'desc')
    .limit(3)
    .get()
    .then(data => {
        let lastVisible = data.docs[data.docs.length-1];
        let posts = [];
        data.forEach(doc => {
            posts.push({
                postID: doc.id,
                body: doc.data().body,
                userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                createdTime: doc.data().createdTime,
                commentCount: doc.data().commentCount,
                likeCount: doc.data().likeCount,
                userImage: doc.data().userImage,
                imagePostUrl: doc.data().imagePostUrl
            });
        });
        return res.json( {posts,last: lastVisible});
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
}
```

This is my second function to get the next posts:

```
exports.fetchMoreData = (req, res) => {
    db.collection('posts')
    .orderBy('createdTime', 'desc')
    .startAfter(req.params.last)
    .limit(3)
    .get()
    .then(data => {
        let lastVisible = data.docs[data.docs.length-1];
        let posts = [];
        data.forEach(doc => {
            posts.push({
                postID: doc.id,
                body: doc.data().body,
                userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                createdTime: doc.data().createdTime,
                commentCount: doc.data().commentCount,
                likeCount: doc.data().likeCount,
                userImage: doc.data().userImage,
                imagePostUrl: doc.data().imagePostUrl
            });
        });
        return res.json( {posts,last: lastVisible});
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
  };
```

[Image about my posts list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAoWK.png)
Someone can help me please :( I have been looking for the answers for days.

_ req.params.last obj :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPgWl.png)

_ data structure of one post :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah9iY.png)

Comment: What is the value of `req.params.last`. As it looks, it should be the value of `createdTime` of the last post that was supplied. Because it is in testing phase, make sure all the timestamp are different.

Comment: Wait what ?? it should be the value of createdTime ? =v= LOL i got req.params.last like the object above I have just added

Comment: after many attempts, req.last.params is still a problem with me, I have tried to pass createdTime like you said above into my app but it not working anyway, can you have a look at the object i add earlier to see which one i should push into my functions ?

Comment: What value are you sending and how does on of the document look like?

Comment: I add the createdTime from _fieldsProto in req.params.last and it not working at all, but if I just add req.params.last it will fetch all the posts although I used startAfter. The document about one post I have just added above

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved my problem, **BIG THANK TO: FRUNKAD** who give me the idea about what need to be passed inside my FecthMoreData functions

_Answer:

```
exports.fetchMoreData = (req, res) => {
    db.collection('posts')
    .orderBy('createdTime', 'desc')
    .startAfter(req.params.last)
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then(data => {
        let lastVisible = data.docs[data.docs.length-1]._fieldsProto.createdTime.stringValue;
        let posts = [];
        data.forEach(doc => {
            posts.push({
                postID: doc.id,
                body: doc.data().body,
                userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                createdTime: doc.data().createdTime,
                commentCount: doc.data().commentCount,
                likeCount: doc.data().likeCount,
                userImage: doc.data().userImage,
                imagePostUrl: doc.data().imagePostUrl
            });
        });
        return res.json( {posts,last: lastVisible});
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
  };
```

**What you need to pass into the startAfter() is what you order your data in Firebase**
also I use "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.5" to implement infiniteScroll, so here is how it look like for anyone using Redux + Firebase + React want to setUp an infiniteScroll :

```
            <InfiniteScroll
                dataLength={this.props.data.posts.length} 
                next={() => this.props.getMorePosts(last)}
                hasMore={this.props.data.posts.length < this.props.data.numberOfPosts ? 
                true : false}
                loader={<p>Loading...</p>}
                endMessage={
                  <p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
                  </p>
                }>
                    {posts.map(post =>{return <Post key={post.postID} passedID={post.postID} name={post.userHandle} post={post} />}) }
                </InfiniteScroll>
```

- dataLength: is the length of the array your posts are stored in redux store
- next : is where you pass your ${function} along with the ${last} ( last in my case is the timestamp I created to orderBy my database )
- hasMore : is where you need to compare your current length of posts array in redux store and all the posts you have (you may need to make an functions from your own api to count how many posts are there to scroll)
- loader is a loader.
- endMessages is the same.